# How to filter dataframe using percentiles to filter out outliers?

Tags: python, pyspark, outliers, percentile

Suppose I have a spark dataframe like this:

```
+------------+-----------+
|category    |value      |
+------------+-----------+
|           a|          1|
|           a|          2|
|           b|          2|
|           a|          3|
|           b|          4|
|           a|          4|
|           b|          6|
|           b|          8|
+------------+-----------+
```

I want to set values higher than 0.75 percentile to nan **for each category**.

That being;

```
a_values = [1,2,3,4] => a_values_filtered = [1,2,3,nan]
b_values = [2,4,6,8] => b_values_filtered = [2,3,6,nan]
```

So the expected output is:

```
+------------+-----------+
|category    |value      |
+------------+-----------+
|           a|          1|
|           a|          2|
|           b|          2|
|           a|          3|
|           b|          4|
|           a|        nan|
|           b|          6|
|           b|        nan|
+------------+-----------+
```

Any idea how to do it cleanly?

PS: I am new to spark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `percent_rank` function to get the percentiles, and then use `when` to assign values > 0.75 percent_rank to `null`.

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import percent_rank,when
w = Window.partitionBy(df.category).orderBy(df.value)
percentiles_df = df.withColumn('percentile',percent_rank().over(w))
result = percentiles_df.select(percentiles_df.category
                               ,when(percentiles_df.percentile <= 0.75,percentiles_df.value).alias('value'))
result.show()
```

Comment: currently I get all values null :) I will take a look and share the results

Comment: most of my values are nans and nulls. so when I sort and percent_rank the values, they also get a rank. Is there a way to ignore nans and nulls in ranking? I also want to preserve the df size, so I don't want to filter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another snippet similar to Prabhala's answer, I use `percentile_approx` UDF instead.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
window = Window.partitionBy('category') 
percentile = F.expr('percentile_approx(value, 0.75)') 
tmp_df = df.withColumn('percentile_value', percentile.over(window))

result = tmp_df.select('category', when(tmp_df.percentile_value >= tmp_df.value, tmp_df.value).alias('value'))
result.show() 

+--------+-----+
|category|value|
+--------+-----+
|       b|    2|
|       b|    4|
|       b|    6|
|       b| null|
|       a|    1|
|       a|    2|
|       a|    3|
|       a| null|
+--------+-----+
```